# Class X is implemented in both places One of the two will be used Which one is undefined M1

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, build

I use Mac M1 and After I upgrade Xcode 13.3.1 , I got this error when I make a build for the project:

```
Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ec461eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103b884f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined
```

here is Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale en-SY)  
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)  
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)  
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web  
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)  
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.3)  
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)  
[✓] Connected device (2 available)  
[✓] HTTP Host Availability  
• No issues found!
```

After I made a search, they said the problem was from flutter_svg library however, I tried to downgrade the version of the library but nothing changed.

Plus I tried these commands:

```
cd ios
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

then these:

```
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

and I still got same error
Any suggestions :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Saw this appear in CodeMagic today when building my Flutter app on their latest M1 units. Xcode 13.3.1 Build version 13E500a w/ Flutter 3.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ee4e09cce0 (9 days ago)

Comment: That's true, so what do I have to do?

Comment: @mustafahasria looks like there is nothing you can do other then to ignore it